# JQuery - How to select the previous table cell of a non empty table cell

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select the previous table cell of a non-empty table cell.

I have the following code.

THIS WORKS (Highlight all empty cells)

```
$("td.brand:empty").css('background-color', 'red');
```

THIS WORKS (Highlight all non empty cells)

```
$("td.brand:not(:empty)").css('background-color', 'green');
```

THIS DOESN'T WORK (Highlight the previous cell of a non empty cell)

```
$("td.brand:not(:empty)").prev("td.brand").css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

All help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a non-working example on jsfiddle? It looks like it should work.

Comment: it should work, please mind that `prev()` will work only on adjacent siblings, not on `td` on other rows

Comment: "Previous cell" means what in this case? The one to the left or the one to the top?

Comment: So what means <<doesn't work>>???

Comment: I just checked your code, and it works fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/kFEqd/

Comment: Yep, clearer example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6hvhJ/ (added a second row to make the cell width clearer)

Comment: This does exactly what you wanted. Or am I missing something?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jRCbd/

Here is my JS Fiddle

Comment: @DavidFregoli Okay I think David has pointed out why this might not be working.  It is in a different row, so how can I take this into account?

Comment: @Johnny check this out http://jsfiddle.net/L3L6a/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to abstract `td`s from their rows you can group them in an object and work with the index:

```
var $tds = $('td.brand');
$tds.filter(":not(:empty)").each(function() {
    var i = $tds.index(this);
    if (i) // prevents wrapping to last
        $tds.eq(i-1).addClass('on');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L3L6a/3/

Comment: This looks good. Can I be so bold as to ask how you would prevent the previous td having this class applied if it does indeed contain an entry itself.  Sometimes there is just one entry per brand and in this use case it look strange.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't have some errors in your JS before the last line because it works.

Your code is right, you can check it here: [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pWVvh/)

This code:

```
$("td.brand:empty").css('background-color', 'red');
$("td.brand:not(:empty)").css('background-color', 'green');
$("td.brand:not(:empty)").prev("td.brand").css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

Works for this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="brand">sdfsdf</td>
        <td class="brand"></td>
        <td class="brand">sdfsdfs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="brand"></td>
        <td class="brand">ssdfsdf</td>
        <td class="brand"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td:not(:empty)").each(function(){
        $(this).prev().css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });
});
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/8zjBq/3/)

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've provided in a comment, there's no previous rows with an empty `td.brand`, so I'm guessing this might be what you need, based on an edit of your example.

```
$("tr:has(td.brand:not(:empty))").prev().find("td.brand").css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

This finds all rows that have a non-empty `td.brand`, then selects the previous row and then the `td.brand` of that row.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jRCbd/1/ (An update of your fiddle)

Comment: This is exactly what I am after but for some reason it does not work on my site but does work in the fiddle.  Any ideas on why that might be?

Comment: If what you provided as an example is the same as your actual solution, I can't say what's wrong, sorry..